# How can public use my Instagram Application?

Tags: javascript, api, instagram

I'm using a JS plugin called 'Instafeed' https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js to dynamically pull in the latest image uploaded to an Instagram account.

My aim is to get this working for a government client. I tested it out on my own personal account first and found my User ID, Client ID and generated a token.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Get the most latest instagram post and insert it into the page in the DIV# instafeed
    var feed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'user',
        userId: '249842490',
        accessToken: '249842490.1677ed0.0283e662751a4e369ae856f60a4b6228',
        sortBy: 'most-recent',
        resolution: 'low_resolution',
        limit: 1,
        clientId: 'dee7958de6a64ed284b95abb1619b790'
    });
    feed.run();
</script>
```

Now to get a Client ID, I had to create an application in the Developers area. From 1st June 2016, any new applications will be sandboxed with limitations applied until it is reviewed and properly published. https://www.instagram.com/developer/limits/

It all works fine and pulls in the image as it should (e.g. https://github.com/SLQ-web/Packery-Mockup-SLQ-Homepage/blob/Ryan's-Responsive-Spec/html/widget-social.html) but I've been quizzed by PM about dependencies and vulnerabilities. I can see obvious dependencies being Instagram account, Instagram Application and the token generator).

I intend to make the Instagram application live as the 500/hour rate limit will be too small for the amount of traffic the page gets. My client seems quite concerned about security once Instagram application is made LIVE.

What I cannot answer is about security risk as in who can use the app? For what purposes? Can someone exploit the application to hack the Instagram account? Mind you I am working for extremely risk adverse client. From what I can only assume is that the application there is used by users who access the page where I have the Instafeed.js calling on the application to generate the content to show. The app is not intended for any other use.

Comment: "Hack the instagram account". What are some examples of what you mean by "hack", other than "somehow logging into the account"?

Comment: Ok, let's forget I used that word (I was quoting). Let's call it inadvertently allowing a user access into a government or corporate Instagram account through the application.

Comment: ok. The only way to login to an Instagram account is with a username/password. Are you worried there is some way to login with a client ID and token or something?

Comment: @JoshBeam but I think people can find his client's `access_token` through view source and use it to spam, which could lead to app and/or account being blocked?

Comment: @HuorCulnamo yes, that's a risk you run by embedding any information on any client device anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Any time you embed information on a client, you run the risk of anyone who has access to that client somehow getting that information. This applies to websites, native mobile apps, etc.

API providers (Instagram in this case) know that this is a risk, and that's why they specifically provide you with some sort of combination of identifiers (in your case `userId`, `accessToken`, and `clientId`) that allow client applications to make requests, but monitor traffic related to those identifiers and provide facilities like throttling traffic, blacklisting, etc.

These types of credentials are useful because they can usually be reset (if you identify some strange traffic coming from a certain source, you can just reset your token and redeploy your application).

This type of thing falls into the realm of "API Management", and these features are pretty common. Unfortunately, the risk of someone getting those keys from your client application is always present.

If the person you're working for doesn't want people to get these credentials, you can implement some sort of user authentication client-side (one of the most common ways nowadays is OAuth, just as an example), and once clients authenticate, they can then make a call to your *server*, and the server would contain the `Instafeed` API and the `userId`, `accessToken`, etc. This just adds an additional layer between the client and Instagram, and allows you to get a little bit more control of who is making requests from your app (it still can't eliminate malicious users who would authenticate from your client-side application, but at least it keeps the access point to Instagram in a separate location, which would be your server).